# How to solve error about "subcommand is required but not givern"?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, error-handling, training-data

Hi guys im trying to run the code clone from github on AWS. But when I want to train the model, I see such error message. Can anyone help to solve it? Thanks a lot[image]

I followed the instruction in README file but failed at the "train bttr model using gpu" step.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, if you could include code and output as text instead of as a screenshot, that would be much appreciated. That way people can copy your code to help debug on their side.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is mostly there in the help message, though it can be a bit obscure if you're new to Python / argparse.

The help message is telling you that you need to use one of the subcommands in your command invocation: `fit`, `validate`, `test`, `predict`, `tune`.

So something like this:

```
python train.py train --config config.yaml
```

As such it seems like the README is incorrect and needs to be updated. You probably want the `train` subcommand given the comment in the README.